# Separating state dependent functions in React top component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, state-management, react-state-management

I am learning react and I reached a problem I can't get past.

On the upmost component I have a lot of functions that depend on state and that modify state. These will get passed on to children components and get linked to event handlers.

The file gets really large and I would like to somehow separate the functions and not clutter all of them in one file.

I created a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mahavira-qlpdt?file=/src/App.js),you can see the App component gets really cluttered with functions.

What options do I have to separate the functions?

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useCallback
} = React;

const useStateWithCallback = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    value: initialState,
    callback: undefined
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.callback) {
      state.callback();
    }
  }, [state]);

  const setStateWithCallback = (newValue, callback) => {
    const value =
      typeof newValue === "function" ? newValue(state.value) : newValue;
    setState({
      value,
      callback
    });
  };
  return [state.value, setStateWithCallback];
};


const Day = ({
  input1,
  input2,
  handleInputChange,
  isLocked,
  index,
  className
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <input
        name="input1"
        value={input1}
        placeholder="lorem"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        readOnly={isLocked}
        data-index={index}
      />
      <input
        name="input2"
        value={input2}
        placeholder="ipsum"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        readOnly={isLocked}
        data-index={index}
      />
    </div>
  );
};



const Menu = ({
  handleSelectChange,
  clearInputs,
  submitInputs,
  handleLock,
  isLocked,
  handleDateChange
}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select name="date" onChange={handleDateChange}>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
      </select>
      <select name="word" onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
        <option value="ipsum">Ipsum</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={clearInputs}>Clear</button>
      <button onClick={submitInputs}>Submit</button>
      {isLocked ? (
        <button onClick={handleLock}>Unlock</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLock}>Lock</button>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};



const Month = ({
  inputs1,
  inputs2,
  handleInputChange,
  isLocked,
  mobile
}) => {
  return ( < React.Fragment >
    <
    Day input1 = {
      inputs1[0]
    }
    input2 = {
      inputs2[0]
    }
    handleInputChange = {
      handleInputChange
    }
    isLocked = {
      isLocked
    }
    index = {
      0
    }
    className = {
      mobile ? "mobile" : "day"
    }
    /> <
    Day input1 = {
      inputs1[1]
    }
    input2 = {
      inputs2[1]
    }
    handleInputChange = {
      handleInputChange
    }
    isLocked = {
      isLocked
    }
    index = {
      1
    }
    className = {
      mobile ? "mobile" : "day"
    }
    /> < /React.Fragment >
  );
};



const App =()=>{
  const [inputs1, setInputs1] = useStateWithCallback(
    Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => "")
  );
  const [inputs2, setInputs2] = useStateWithCallback(
    Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => "")
  );
  const [word, setWord] = useState("?");
  const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useStateWithCallback(false);
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(true);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().getDate());
  const handleSelectChange = event => {
    setWord(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    if (event.target.name === "input1") {
      const newInputs1 = [...inputs1];
      newInputs1[event.target.dataset.index] =
        event.target.value.length === 3
          ? event.target.value + word
          : event.target.value;
      setInputs1(newInputs1);
    } else if (event.target.name === "input2") {
      const newInputs2 = [...inputs2];
      newInputs2[event.target.dataset.index] =
        event.target.value.length === 4
          ? event.target.value + word + "%%"
          : event.target.value;
      setInputs2(newInputs2);
    }
  };

  const clearInputsOnServer = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800))
      .catch(() => console.log(`couldn't clear`))
      .then(console.log("succesfully cleared inputs on server"));
  };

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setInputs1(
      Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => ""),
      setInputs2(Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => ""), clearInputsOnServer)
    );
  };

  const submitInputs = () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800))
      .catch(() => console.log(`couldn't update`))
      .then(console.log("submitted inputs to server"));
  };

  const updateLockOnServer = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800))
      .catch(() => console.log(`couldn't update`))
      .then(console.log("updated lock status on server"));
  };

  const handleLock = () => {
    setIsLocked(wasLocked => !wasLocked, updateLockOnServer);
  };

  let timeout = useRef();
  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      const newMobile = window.innerWidth <= 600 ? true : false;
      if (mobile !== newMobile) setMobile(newMobile);
    }, 300);
  }, [mobile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, [handleResize]);

  const handleDateChange = event => {
    setDate(event.target.value);
  };

  const getValuesFromServer = useRef(() => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800))
      .then(console.log("succesfully updated inputs from server"))
      .catch(() => {});
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getValuesFromServer.current();
  }, [date]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu
        handleSelectChange={handleSelectChange}
        clearInputs={clearInputs}
        submitInputs={submitInputs}
        handleLock={handleLock}
        isLocked={isLocked}
        handleDateChange={handleDateChange}
      />
      <Month
        inputs1={inputs1}
        inputs2={inputs2}
        handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
        isLocked={isLocked}
        mobile={mobile}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}



const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <
  React.StrictMode >
  <
  App/ >
  <
  /React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile input {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can abstract scopes from your code into separate hooks folder than call into you `App` component extracting only what you need. for example all your lock state logic could be a hook like:

```
// useLockHandler.js at your hooks folder

const useLockHandler = () => { 
 const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useStateWithCallback(false);

 const updateLockOnServer = () => {
    fetch(`server`, {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        isLocked
      })
    })
      .catch(() => console.log(`couldn't update`))
      .then(console.log("updated lock status on server"));
  };

  const handleLock = () => {
    setIsLocked(wasLocked => !wasLocked, updateLockOnServer);
  };

// expose what you need at your component.you can return as array or object
  return { isLocked, handleLock }
}

export default useLockHandler
```

than at your `App` you would import `useLockHandler` and extract the variables you need:

```
export default function App() {
  // all other states setting
  const { isLocked, handleLock } = useLockHandler()
```